# Oracle: Make a composite Key containing three Foregin keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite

This is my code:

```
create table orderline
(
Order_No number(4) constraint orderno_fk references order_detail(Order_No),
Product_Code varchar2(6) constraint productcode2_fk references product(Product_Code),
Product_Size char(1) constraint productsize_fk references product_stock(Product_Size),
Product_Quantity number(4) not null
constraint orderline_comp primary key (Order_No,Product_Code, Product_Size)
);
```

I get the error (with the star underneath the left parenthesis before 'Order'):

```
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `,` before the `constraint orderline...`